# connect input with data (Shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

i'm new to R and shiny and also new to this forum.

I need to build a shiny app but struggle to connect the inputs with my imported data.

This is what i have so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)




ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage(title="Impfdashboard",
               tabPanel("Impffortschritt",
                        sliderInput(inputId="dateRangeSlider", "KW Waehlen:",
                                                 min = 1,
                                                 max = 21,
                                                 value = c(1, 21),
                                                 step = 1,
                                                 width = 8000),
                        
                        checkboxGroupInput(inputId="status", "Impfstatus:",
                                           c("Erstimpfung" = "erst",
                                             "Zweitimpfung" = "zweit",
                                             "Gesamtanzahl der Impfungen" = "gesamt")),
                        
                        mainPanel(width = "100%", plotOutput("linechart", width = "100%"))
               ),
               tabPanel("Impfstoff Info",
                        sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput(inputId="bundeslaender", "Bundeslaender:",
                                                 c("Baden-Wuerttemberg" = "BW",
                                                   "Bayern" = "BY",
                                                   "Berlin" = "BE",
                                                   "Brandenburg" = "BB",
                                                   "Bremen" = "HB",
                                                   "Hamburg" = "HH",
                                                   "Hessen" = "HE",
                                                   "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern" = "MV",
                                                   "Niedersachsen" = "NI",
                                                   "Nordrhein-Westfalen" = "NW",
                                                   "Rheinland-Pfalz" = "RP",
                                                   "Saarland" = "SL",
                                                   "Sachsen" = "SN",
                                                   "Sachsen-Anhalt" = "ST",
                                                   "Schleswig-Holstein" = "SH",
                                                   "Thueringen" = "TH",
                                                   "Impfzentren Bund" = "Bund",
                                                   "Gesamt" = "GES")),
                                     
                                     
                                     ),
                        mainPanel(width = "100%", plotOutput("barchart", width = "100%"))
               )
    )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$linechart <- renderPlot({
        
     ggplot(data=impfungenNachKW, aes(x = KW, y = gesamt)) + 
            geom_line(color= "blue") +
            geom_point() +
            labs(x= "Kalenderwoche", y= "Anzahl der Impfungen", title ="Impffortschritt pro KW (von KW 1 bis einschliesslich KW 21 2021)") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,21, by=1)) +
            scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
        
    })
    
    output$barchart <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(data=impfstoff, aes(x = Impfstoff, y = Gesamt)) +
        geom_bar(fill="Steelblue", stat = "identity") +
        labs(y = "Anzahl der Impfungen") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))+
        geom_text(aes(label=Gesamt), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)    
        
        
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

On app page 1 I want to show three linecharts depending on what is selected in checkboxGroupInput "status" and which calendar week is selected in sliderInput "dateRangeSlider".

On page 2 it should show the amount of vaccine used by manufacturer in the different states which are choosen by checkboxGroupInput "bundeslaender".

Looking forward to your help and to get some new stuff I can learn. :)

Screenshots of the data used and current status:

[dataset impfstoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjrOm.png)

[dataset impfungenNachKW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqPdd.png)

[app page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEROZ.png)

[app page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsRpV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidyverse solution: You use your inputs to filter the dataset, right before plotting it. Therefore you need to get the data in long format with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` before. 
 Afterwards you can filter here:

```
impfstoff %>%
  filter(location == input$bundeslaender) %>%
  filter(time > input$dateRangeSlider[1]) %>%
  filter(time < input$dateRangeSlider[2]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Impfstoff, y = Gesamt))
```

To make my solution easier to understand, i added some tables on top filled with sample data. It's always super useful if u provide a minimalistic sample of your data in code, not in a picture.

I updated a lot of code and hopefully commented most parts!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse) #need this (awesome) package for this solution

# i guess thats how your data looks like
impfstoff.wide <- tibble(
  Bayern = c(10,20,30),
  Berlin = c(40,50,60),
  Bremen = c(70,80,90),
  Impfstoff = c("Astra","Biontech","Moderna"))

# getting data into long format here
impfstoff.long <- pivot_longer(impfstoff.wide, Bayern:Bremen, names_to = "Bundesland", values_to = "Gesamt")

# i guess thats how your other data looks like
impfungenNachKW <- tibble(
  KW = c(1:5),
  erst = c(1000,2000,3500,5500,7500),
  zweit = c(NA,500,1000,2000,7500),
  gesamt = c(1000,2500,4500,7500,15000),
)
# getting data into long format here
impfungenNachKW.long <- pivot_longer(impfungenNachKW, erst:gesamt, names_to = "Status",values_to = "Gesamt")


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title="Impfdashboard",
             tabPanel("Impffortschritt",
                      sliderInput(inputId="dateRangeSlider", "KW Waehlen:",
                                  min = 1,
                                  max = 21,
                                  value = c(1, 21),
                                  step = 1,
                                  width = 8000),
                      
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId="status", "Impfstatus:",
                                         c("Erstimpfung" = "erst",
                                           "Zweitimpfung" = "zweit",
                                           "Gesamtanzahl der Impfungen" = "gesamt"),
                                         selected = "erst"), #added default status
                      
                      mainPanel(width = "100%", plotOutput("linechart", width = "100%"))
             ),
             tabPanel("Impfstoff Info",
                      sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput(inputId="bundeslaender", "Bundeslaender:",
                                                      c("Bayern" = "Bayern",
                                                        "Berlin" = "Berlin",
                                                        "Bremen" = "Bremen"),
                                                      selected = "Bayern"), #added default bundesland
                                   
                                   
                      ),
                      mainPanel(width = "100%",verbatimTextOutput("check"), plotOutput("barchart", width = "100%"))#the check is just to show whats in there
             )
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$check <- renderText(c(input$bundeslaender)) #just to show whats in there
  
  output$linechart <- renderPlot({
    
    datenfürmeinenplot <- impfungenNachKW.long %>% #this data will used in the plot below
      filter(KW >= input$dateRangeSlider[1]) %>% #here u refer to lower slider
      filter(KW <= input$dateRangeSlider[2]) %>% #here u refer to upper slider
      filter(Status %in% input$status) #here u select the status
    
    
    ggplot(data=datenfürmeinenplot, aes(x = KW, y = Gesamt, group = Status, color = Status)) + 
      geom_line()+
      geom_point() +
      labs(x= "Kalenderwoche", y= "Anzahl der Impfungen", title ="Impffortschritt pro KW (von KW 1 bis einschliesslich KW 21 2021)") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,21, by=1)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
    
  })
  
  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(data=impfstoff.long %>% filter(Bundesland %in% input$bundeslaender), aes(x = Bundesland, y = Gesamt, fill = Impfstoff)) +
      geom_col(position=position_stack())+ #chenged here
      geom_text(aes(label=Impfstoff),size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+ #changed here
      labs(y = "Anzahl der Impfungen") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15, face = "bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
    #geom_text(aes(label=Gesamt), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)    #dont need this one then
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer but i'm still confused. I try to understand but where does "location" and "time" come from? Where do I have to put these?

So far i tried the following:

newImpfstoff <- pivot_longer(impfstoff, c(BadenWuerttemberg, Bayern, Berlin, Brandenburg, Bremen, Hamburg, Hessen, MecklenburgVorpommern, Niedersachsen, NordrheinWestfalen, RheinlandPfalz, Saarland, Sachsen, SachsenAnhalt, SchleswigHolstein, Thueringen, Bund, Gesamt))

But I can't check if this worked, at least I don't get a error for it.

Comment: edited my answer, changed a lot of your original code to explain what i meant in the original answer. hopefully i can help you! :-)